# Third party Css is not working with angular component

Tags: angular

I am using a third party css and js, i had copied all the folders in the assets folder and giving the link of the files in the style.css still the css is not working. I tried to directly give the path in angular.json file but still its not working

```js
@import "assets/css/style.css";
@import "assets/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
@import "assets/lib/animate/animate.min.css";
@import "assets/lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css";
@import "assets/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css";
@import "assets/lib/lightbox/css/lightbox.min.css";`

`<header id="header" class="fixed-top">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="logo float-left">
            <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
            <!-- <h1 class="text-light"><a href="#header"><span>NewBiz</span></a></h1> -->
            <a href="#intro" class="scrollto"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>

          <nav class="main-nav float-right d-none d-lg-block">
            <ul>
              <li class="active"><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
              <li class="drop-down"><a href="">Drop Down</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>
                  <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Drop Down 2</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 4</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Drop Down 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Drop Down 4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Drop Down 5</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav><!-- .main-nav -->

        </div>
      </header>
```

Comment: does it says `404` for those files  ?

Comment: it does not show any error

Comment: can you try with adding src path on your importing  path e.g @import 'src/assets/css/sidebar-nav.min.css'; As Absolute path in styleUrls is not trivial in angular

Comment: yup i tried, but no effect. i am linking all the imports in style.css